# nsdateformatter not working with japanese calendar

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I'm seeing a problem with NSDateFormatter on iOS when Settings/General/International/Calendar is set to either Japanese or Buddhist on both the simulator and a real device. The year is not parsed correctly

DateFormatter

```
static NSDateFormatter *formatter = nil;  // cache this the first time through


if (formatter == nil) {
    formatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
    formatter.locale = [[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"] autorelease]; // Fix for QC79748 - Michael Marceau
    formatter.dateFormat = @"EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz";
    formatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"EST"];
    formatter.calendar = [[[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar] autorelease];
    formatter.locale = [[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:[[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0]] autorelease];


}

NSLog(@"CorrectDate%@",[serviceHeaders safeObjectForKey:@"Date"] );
    NSLog(@"Formatted date:%@",[formatter dateFromString:[serviceHeaders safeObjectForKey:@"Date"]]);

Output

Correct - Mon, 27 Aug 2012 16:33:14 GMT
Formatted date:0024-08-27 16:33:14 +0000
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is working just as it should. I took your code and added it to my project, then set the Simulator to use the Buddhist calendar.

```
NSLog(@"date=%@", [NSDate date]);
2012-08-27 18:42:10.201 Searcher[43537:f803] date=2555-08-27 22:42:10 +0000

    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
    formatter.locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"]; // Fix for QC79748 - Michael Marceau
    formatter.dateFormat = @"EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz";
    formatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"EST"];
    formatter.calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    //formatter.locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:[[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0]];
```

Then the output:

```
NSLog(@"CorrectDate%@", @"Mon, 27 Aug 2012 16:33:14 GMT" );
2012-08-27 18:42:10.203 Searcher[43537:f803] CorrectDateMon, 27 Aug 2012 16:33:14 GMT

NSLog(@"Formatted date:%@",[formatter dateFromString:@"Mon, 27 Aug 2012 16:33:14 GMT"]);
2012-08-27 18:42:10.206 Searcher[43537:f803] Formatted date:2555-08-27 16:33:14 +0000
```

Analysis:

Its all working perfectly. In the Buddhist calendar, the year is 2555 now. When you provide a Gregorian date, and ask the formatter to use the Gregorian calendar, it reads it in properly, then converts it to the Buddhist date, and when you print that out, the date is 2555 again. Just what you would expect.

EDIT: Just to press the point, the NSDate is always the same, what changes is the representation of it. So I set the calendar to Buddhist again, and used your formatter to get the current time in Gregorian time:

```
NSLog(@"date=%@", [NSDate date]);
NSLog(@"Date using the Gregorian calendar: %@", [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]);
```

outputs

```
2012-08-28 07:13:10.658 Searcher[69194:f803] date=2555-08-28 11:13:10 +0000
2012-08-28 07:13:10.660 Searcher[69194:f803] Date using the Gregorian calendar: Tue, 28 Aug 2012 07:13:10 EDT
```

PS: your code sets locale twice.

Comment: Thank you for looking at it. But I want the output in Gregorian calendar no matter what calendar is selected in the simulator. Would you know how I can  do that?

Comment: NSDate is always the same - its the representation of it that is changing when the System Calendar is changed.

Comment: Can we prevent the user from changing that? Or can we force the representation to always be Gregorian (in the app) even if user changes it in the settings?

Comment: No, you cannot prevent the user from changing it. Whether to force all dates to be shown in Gregorian is a design decision that only you can make. Good luck!

Comment: Yup. I want to force the dates to be only in the Gregorian format. Could you please help me how I can do that. I am initializing the calendar with Gregorian style but still it refers to selected Japanese or Buddhist calendar

Comment: You don't change the dates - you cannot. You cannot change the users calendar. But what you can do is always format the string you display to the user to be Gregorian, just as I did using your formatter. Your problem is a presentation issue, not a model issue.